# Merge two reformatted PHP files with GIT

Tags: php, git, merge, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

We have two branches in GIT with some PHP-files. All we need to do is to merge one into another.

Unfortunately, there are two huge files that was auto-reformatted with our IDEs (spaces, braces, line-breaks etc). When we try to merge them, GIT shows a hell of a lot of conflicts, that are not humanly possible to resolve by hand.

We've tried approach described at this post:
http://blog.wuwon.id.au/2010/09/painless-merge-conflict-resolution-in.html
but we can't even see the actual changes (base > local, remote > local), because we can't even distinguish actual semantic changes from just a syntactic ones (lots of code, easy to miss something).

We are working right now on an old code, that needs a lot of refactoring and reformatting done (code standard PSR 0-2), so this situation will be common.

Please advise how to deal with this problem in a most effective way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Does the file itself differ from one branch to another, functionality-wise? Easiest thing would - obviously - be to ditch either of them. I don't see how you could solve these kind of conflicts automagically. Furthermore, I'd suggest you format files like this ones, push those files to the master branch and go from there. Reformatting the same file twice doesn't sound very convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, looks like both files were reformatted, and yes, both of them include functionality changes.